# unable to create and set cookie to handle JSESSSIONID

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

We have a Java based application which downloads files from a website

Have to login to access the content of the website (and to download)

All these are done as part of this Java application using Apache HttpClient 4.3.3

Unfortunately the code implemented logins all the time and creates unwanted sessions (~10000+) on the web server

The website once logins it provides a JSESSSIONID as part of the cookie.

What I thought of was getting this JSESSIONID from cookie and create cookie and set it as part of next calls.

Following is what I had done

- After the first execute of the url, I read the JSESSIONID from cookie and store in a text file
- During the second run, I get read the text file and get the value of JSESSIONID and create a cookie and set it
- Call the execute of `ClosableHTTPClient` I pass the context along with the cookie

Below is my code snippet

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = null;
httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().useSystemProperties().build();
HttpClientContext  localContext = HttpClientContext.create();
BasicCookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
cookie.setDomain("sso.comp.com");
cookie.setPath("/");            
cookie.setAttribute("JSESSIONID", "dfafdffddasfad32423423_!ad");
cookieStore.addCookie(cookie);
localContext.setAttribute(HttpClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
localContext.setCookieStore(cookieStore);
CloseableHttpResponse response = null;
response = httpClient.execute(get,localContext);
```

This always results in HTTP 401 Unauthorized

Note that my application is called every time from scratch to download but in a space of few seconds /minutes

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: How about storing the cookie itself as an in-memory object somewhere and use it again?

Comment: Issue is the application closes and  starts fresh within a span of 60 mins multiple times.

Comment: IN my opinion, something is going wrong in a way the cookies are serialized/deserialized. So I would like to check if there is any option to use any other option than writing to a file.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the cookie the wrong way. The method `setAttribute` is used to set [cookie attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Cookie_attributes)

```
CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
BasicClientCookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie("JSESSIONID", "dfafdffddasfad32423423_!ad");
cookie.setDomain("sso.comp.com");
cookie.setPath("/");
cookie.setAttribute(ClientCookie.DOMAIN_ATTR, "true");
cookieStore.addCookie(cookie);
```

To verify the cookie is sent in the write format you can enable [http client wire traces](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/logging.html) or sniff HTTP traffic...